# Styling through javascript matchmedia not working

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone, 
        I have tried to disable the images for certain device width and its not working, here's the code: 
 Html

```
<figure id="quote-one">
<blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do</blockquote>
<figcaption>Dummy text  </figcaption>
<img src="http://65.media.tumblr.com/avatar_b557ab7102d7_6.png"> 
</figure>
```

javascript

```
<script>
window.matchMedia( "(min-width: 20em)" and ("max-width:45em"))
.addListener( function( mm ){
if( mm.matches ){
var el= document.querySelector("#quote-one").getElementsByTagName("img")[0]
el.style.display = "none";}
} );
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a56019r4/
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for your media query string is incorrect. The [logical `and` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#Logical_operators) belongs in the string like this:

```
window.matchMedia("(min-width: 20em) and (max-width:45em)")
```

Additionally, note that this event is only fired when then media *changes* so you're going to have to perform an action to get the event fired (maybe try changing the orientation of your display).

You can see the code in action in the snippet below:

```js
window.matchMedia("(min-width: 20em) and (max-width:45em)").addListener(function(mm) {
  var el = document.querySelector("#quote-one img");
  if (mm.matches) {
    el.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    el.style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```html
<figure id="quote-one">
  <blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</blockquote>
  <figcaption>Dummy text</figcaption>
  <img src="http://65.media.tumblr.com/avatar_b557ab7102d7_64.png">
</figure>
```

Here's a fixed version of your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/a56019r4/2/